# Stuck on Caesar Cypher Encryption (beginner)

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

Okay, I'm a complete noob and very confused. I'm doing the encryption for a caesar cypher. When I passed "aaa" into it, the encryption spit out "baa". Didn't make sense to me but I thought, maybe it's not cycling through the for-loop. So I typed in "abc" (and abc...y) and it works then. Even stranger, I get a "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" when I write "fell" into it (and shift over only once -- I expect an IndexError if I tried to shift it over 20). I figured it might have something to do with double ls as it didn't work with aaa, but when I put "fel" into it, I get the same IndexError (still only shifting it over one space). And that makes no sense (to me) because "abc...y" worked, and that obviously includes "f", "e", and "l".

Thank you. Here's my code:

````
direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))

def encrypt(text, shift):
    text_list = list(text)
    cypher = text_list.copy()
    for position in text:
        place = alphabet.index(position)
        cypher_place = place + shift
        cypher[place] = alphabet[cypher_place]
    cypher_text = "".join(cypher)
    print(cypher_text)

encrypt(text, shift)```
````

Comment: Please provide a [mre]; in particular, you have not shown how `alphabet` is initialized. One obvious problem is that you need to wrap around when the shift goes past `z`, so that `z` plus a shift of 1 produces `a`, `z` plus 2 produces `b`, etc. This is a very common beginner assignment; please review existing questions.

Answer (score 0):

`cypher[place]` is the nth element of your cypher text where n is the position of the current letter in the alphabet, not it's position in the plaintext.  You can use 'enumerate' to get both the letter at the current position AND the current position.

```
[...]
    for position, character in enumerate(text):
        place = alphabet.index(character)
        cypher_place = place + shift
        cypher[position] = alphabet[cypher_place]
[...]
```